# is it a good idea to allow users to close questions easily?

Tags: discussion

Also on meta? I would deny it. How do you change wrong community rules if the people who made that rule can mark a question as dup and close it?

Doesn't it limit too much the freedom of expression?

I'm seeing this community going toward a police state for window dressing reason.

Too broad.. too opinionable.. the name of the section is "software reccomendation"

Answer (score 4):

> is it a good idea to allow users to close questions easily?

Then when you want people to start closing questions? When we all have 200 rep? 3000 rep? 10000 rep?

We need to be able to close questions on sight since we need to shape our standards and what we want this site made of. If we wait and sit idly without doing anything things will get unmanageable and the site will perish.

> How do you change wrong community rules if the people who made that rule can mark a question as dup and close it?

Bring it to meta and discuss it. Why you think some question should remain open/closed? Expose your ideas, just not bash out some believes without specifics cases that we could discuss constructively.

> Doesn't it limit too much the freedom of expression?

You move to a communal house, sharing a roof with different people. We share cost and expenditures of the house. There are more people living there. They all agreed on some terms that were explained to you before you moved and until you accepted them you couldn't move in.

You think you are being limited your freedom? You **agreed with it before hand**. You should already know the house rules and you should know that to change it you need to discuss it with the residents. You can't just walk in, throw a tantrum saying that everything is wrong without identifying any specific problem or propose a solution. What gives?

BTW, you are still a kind of visitant here. You first have to observe what do romans do so you can speak about improving it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason close votes (as opposed to downvotes) arn't anonymous - If someone feels enough that your question should be on hold, they're perfectly willing to put their names behind it.

I voted to close at least one of three (maybe two of them, I don't entirely remember) of your meta questions because the covered the exact same ground over subjective (good, better and so on) wording. I felt that a single question was enough, and 3 questions on the same ground, by the same user was clearly duplication. Where possible, I've also attempted to let you know where I felt there's an issue (though granted, I've occationally been annoyed enough to say nothing at all, rather than something angry).

As always, its useful to understand that there's checks and balances already in place. You need 5 closevotes from regular users (and until we get our temporary moderators) or one closevote from a SE community manager.

The idea of wrong community rules is baffling when SE sites are heavily community run. One would assume that community rules make more sense than having random individuals dictate how things should be run without any reason other than their say so.